# Are D-Bus and Hal needed for a virtual server?

Tags: linux, hal

I have a Xen-based Centos 5.5 virtual machine running as a server - Apache, OpenSSH, MySQL, Tomcat, Nagios and ISC Bind. It is currently running both `d-bus` and `hal-daemon`. Are these needed or can I safely turn them off?

Comment: an old question but ... what about if the VM runs an headless openoffice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you can turn them off if nothing needs them. Kill D-Bus, and if nothing rolls over or complains then you can kill hal as well. "And the like" isn't specific enough to give any sort of an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the list of main apps which are running on the machine. I stopped them, and nothing seems to complain in `/var/log/messages` or other locations. Is there anything specific I should be looking for?

Comment: Not really. Just... stuff not working as usual. The apps you list don't normally use either, so you're probably fine.